# Error in flextable in r: Error in get_rows_id(x[[part]], i) : invalid row selection. `length(i)` [1] != `nrow(dataset)` [6]

Tags: r, flextable

In flextable in R, I am trying to conditional formatting. For example, if a column is a positive number, I would like the color "green". And if the number is negative, I would like the color "red". But my code only works when my table in one row.

When my table is more than one row I get the following error:

Error in get_rows_id(x[[part]], i) :
invalid row selection. `length(i)` [1] != `nrow(dataset)` [6].

Please help. Im stuck. I read the documentation but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It says your `i` has length 1 but your table has 6 rows. Without a reproducible example, we can't help you. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?